# Casting void pointer to long type, not pointer long?

Tags: c, pointers

```
 int cmpLong(void *a, void *b) {
    long aa = (long)a;
    long bb = (long)b;
    return aa - bb;
}
```

I don't really understand the purpose of this piece of  code what is it comparing? When a void pointer is casted as a long is it an arbitrary number or does it still hold some meaning?

I have re-written the piece of code to allow for comparison between `void *a and void *b`

Here is the code that I have re-written:

```
int cmpLong(void *a, void *b) {
    // casting void pointers to long pointers
    long *aa = (long*)a;
    long *bb = (long*)b;
    return *aa - *bb;
}
```

This makes more sense to me but I don't know whether it is doing the same thing as the original code.

Comment: Your change makes the code behave differently: you are comparing what the pointers point to, whereas the original code is comparing the addresses of what the pointers point to.   You'll have to consult the rest of the codebase to work out what this function is supposed to do (unless the original coder wrote documentation for this function)

Comment: A pointer is in fact the address of the data it points to, and that's why you can convert it to a number.

Comment: `(long)a` attempts to convert the address stored in `a` to a number. This may or may not be possible depending on your system (it causes undefined behaviour if it is not possible), and it's a bad idea in any case. The types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` exist for this purpose.

Comment: so it converts the hexidecimal address into a long?

Comment: Yes it is for quicksort actually!

Comment: "hexadecimal" is not a property of addresses . Addresses are often converted to hex in order to print them but they aren't hex by nature

Comment: If this is for quicksort then it's likely that your re-written version is the intended implementation, and the original would never have worked

Comment: Would there be a reason to compare the value of the pointers when re-cast as long?

Comment: If it's in a quicksort, then no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These do different things entirely.

```
 int cmpLong(void *a, void *b) {
    long aa = (long)a;
    long bb = (long)b;
    return aa - bb;
}
```

This is comparing two addresses.  It will return the number of bytes difference between the two address values.  To understand this, let's give them some numbers and play computer.

```
a = 0x2000;
b = 0x1000;
long aa = (long)a; // So aa = 0x1000.  Casting only changes the type, not the value.
long bb = (long)b; // bb = 0x2000.
return aa - bb;    // 0x2000 - 0x1000 => returns 0x1000
```

Now let's look at your example, which is doing quite a different thing.

```
int cmpLong(void *a, void *b) {
    // casting void pointers to long pointers
    long *aa = (long*)a;
    long *bb = (long*)b;
    return *aa - *bb;
}
```

Playing the same game:

```
a = 0x2000;
b = 0x1000;
long* aa = (long*)a;  // aa = 0x1000.  Casting still doesn't change the value.
long* bb = (long*)b;  // bb = 0x2000.
return *aa - *bb;     // *aa is the data at 0x1000.  This data is treated as a long value.
                      // *bb is the data at 0x2000, again treated as a long value.
                      // so *aa - *bb is the difference between the values at 0x2000 and 0x1000 when read as longs.
```

Comment: `a = 0x2000;` needs to be `a = (void *)0x2000;` if you want this to be compilable

Comment: I don't want that to be compileable.  The *reader* is playing computer.  No compiler needed.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I just learned the hard way that you cannot cast a pointer to long and expect to be able to cast it back to a pointer. Negative pointer values won't survive the conversion: the highest bit will get duplicated.

Maybe unsigned long would work, but since I was passing the value via swig to java, which doesn't have unsigned integer types, I wasn't able to try that.

Comment: you were probably on Windows 64bit and would have needed `long long` to fit a pointer:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types
Check out `std::intptr_t`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: I was using 64-bit linux.

Comment: What's the size of your pointer? I am not sure if it's still an issue if the pointer size match the "long" size